# Checking if all values are equal in two vectors

Tags: for-loop, vector, vhdl

I have two `std_logic_vectors` `RA` and `RB` and I want to perform the following algorithm on them:

```
for i = 0 to 15 loop
    if RA(i) = RB(i) then RT(i) <= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    else RT(i) <= 0x00000000;
    end if;
end loop;
```

Basically, i want to compare the two vectors with each other (in this case, bit by bit) and see they are equal. If yes, then i set my output vector `RT` to be all ones, else, `RT` is all zeros.

What's a good way of doing this? I could probably brute force some implementation but i'd rather do it a smart way.

Thanks,

Comment: The syntax in your question is somewhat messed up. What do you mean by **by 4**? How are RA, RB, RT declared? Are they signals or variables?

Comment: The "by 4" part of my comment above refers to a previous version of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if (RA = RB) then
    RT <= (others => '1');
else
    RT <= (others => '0');
end if;
```

Assuming RT is a subtype of `std_logic_vector` as well. No need for a loop, the comparison operator is defined for `std_logic_vector`s (of equal dimension).